# Copy a file content using event receivers?

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

I want to know if there is any way by which I can make a copy of the file which is being added to a document library using c# event receiver and further convert it to pdf in SharePoint 2010  ?

i.e If a file A is being uploaded to Document Library Test then using Item Added event receiver I want to create a copy of the File A say File B and convert it into B.pdf programmatically.

Is it possible ?

How?

Note : I know how to convert to pdf but dont know how can I make a copy of the document?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SPFile.CopyTo` method.

[SPFile.CopyTo Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ms455020(v=office.14).aspx)

Example:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSite.AllWebs["Site_Name/Subsite_Name"])
{
    SPFileCollection collFiles = oWebsite.GetFolder("Shared 
        Documents").Files;

    for (int intIndex=0; intIndex<collFiles.Count; intIndex++)
    {
        collFiles[intIndex].CopyTo("Destination_DocLib/" + 
            collFiles[intIndex].Name, true);
    }
}
```

You could also use the `SPFileCollection.Add` method.

[SPFileCollection.Add Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ms367739(v=office.14).aspx)

Example:

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
    using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["MyWebSite"])
    {
        SPWebCollection collWebsites = oWebsite.Webs;
        SPFile oFile = oWebsite.GetFile("MyDocLib/MyFile");
        foreach (SPWeb oWebsiteNext in collWebsites)
        {
            SPFolder oFolder = oWebsiteNext.GetFolder("Shared Documents");
            SPFileCollection collFiles = oFolder.Files;

            string strDestUrl = oFolder.Url + "/" + oFile.Name;
            byte[] binFile = oFile.OpenBinary();
            collFiles.Add(strDestUrl, binFile);

            oWebsiteNext.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```