# Convert document to pdf using event receiver in SharePoint 2010 not working

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, word-automation

I followed steps on [this link](https://sharepointsamurai.wordpress.com/category/document-conversion/) to convert a word document being added to pdf format using a custom event receiver. I was able to attach the receiver and trigger the code written but somehow the conversion didn't took place.

I double checked the code and for the Word Automation Service Instance both of them is correct and working respectively. The code get debugged without any error in the debugger but doesn't outputs the resulting pdf file.

what am I missing ?

Thank You,

Comment: Is the file that you're trying to convert a copy of another file, as you asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159457/copy-a-file-content-using-event-receivers/159463#159463? What do you end up with at the moment, just the copy of the file, or not even the copy?

Comment: no its not a copy,

Comment: I tried two approaches

1: i used the content organizer function and tried configuring the event receiver on the destination drop-off library 

and

2: Created a separate document library and added the event receiver to that .

in both cases the code works well and gets debugged but the file is not getting converted.

Comment: "The conversion does not occur immediately, but is processed during the next run of the conversion job." Are you sure this is not the reason you're not seeing a PDF file?

Comment: i waited for almost an hour but still the result is not there,

Comment: what else can be the reason for this, the service is running.

Comment: Troubleshooting help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff808318(v=office.14).aspx and https://www.diversus.com.au/Blog/DeepDive-SharePoint-2010-Word-Automation-Services. Check the event viewer for errors and check the last time the service ran.